# Center text in div with border-radius

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I want to vertical and horizontal center text in only one div which has a surrounding circle made with border-radius. Currently the text is shown in the lower right corner tho...

Look here for the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gvoyu830/

My css:

```
DIV {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10%;
  border: 1.2em solid #dddddd;
  border-radius: 50%;
  max-width: 1.2em;
  max-height: 1.2em;
  box-sizing: border-box;    
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It can be achieved simply by setting `height`/`width` of divs and a `line-height` which is equal to the `height` in order for vertical alignment.

`text-align: center` will do the horizontal alignment.

```css
div {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    /* width: 10%; */
    /* border: 1.2em solid #dddddd; */
    background-color: #ddd;
    width: 2.4em;
    height: 2.4em;
    line-height: 2.4em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    /* max-width: 1.2em; */
    /* max-height: 1.2em; */
    /* box-sizing: border-box; */    
    /* margin: 0 auto; */
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/gvoyu830/1/   `Center in a circle`

I did it for you, but only with relative position. (else, the text align: center; don't exactely works because the begin of your string is the left of the number)

Comment: I do want to use only one element, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gvoyu830/2/)

Add

```
text-align:center;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
```

Example:

```
DIV {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10%;
    border: 1.2em solid #dddddd;
    border-radius: 50%;
    max-width: 1.2em;
    max-height: 1.2em;
    box-sizing: border-box;    
    margin: 0 auto;
   text-align:center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;

}
```

Comment: Lol, beautiful circles !

Comment: the gray should be filled, can that be achieved with your solution?

Comment: well my fault... just use background-color :D

Answer (score 1):

Really want to contribute. This is what I've got:

```
DIV {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 10%;
    border: 1.5em solid #dddddd;
    border-radius: 50%;
    max-width: 1.15em;
    max-height: 1.15em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Fiddle **[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/alicera/1zt9vfby/)**

**UPDATED**: (with background the same as border color)
[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alicera/1zt9vfby/5/)